# Stacked Bar-chart based on bool value column Altair

Tags: pandas, altair

I'm trying to do something like below.

Group by the date column, for example year or year/month. 
And visualize a stacked bar chart, based on the True/False value.

What's the best way to go about this in Altair?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['20-03-2017', '20-03-2017', '20-03-2018', '21-03-2018', '20-10-2019', '20-03-2019', '1-02-2019', '10-03-2020', '20-06-2020'],
    'value': [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
})

import altair as alt
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'groupbyyear(date)',
    y = 'count(value)',
    color = 'value'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close: instead of `groupbyyear` you can use a `year` [time unit transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html#user-guide-timeunit-transform), and since your dates are non-standard format, you can first use pandas [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert them to standard date values. The result looks like this:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['20-03-2017', '20-03-2017', '20-03-2018', '21-03-2018', '20-10-2019', '20-03-2019', '1-02-2019', '10-03-2020', '20-06-2020'],
    'value': [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'year(date):O',
    y = 'count(value)',
    color = 'value'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Just to follow-up:
Would it als be possible to show the True/False count seperately in the tooltip?

‘tooltip = ‘count(value)’ only shows the aggregate

Comment: Post another question with more information about what you want the tooltip to show.

Comment: Sure! I created a new question.